# How to check for words in a list and then return a count?

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and have a question:

I am trying to write a script that will read a .txt file and check if words are in a list that I've provided and then return a count as to how many words were in that list.

So far,

```
import string
#this is just an example of a list
list = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']

filename="hi.txt"
infile=open(filename, "r")
lines = infile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation)
```

I've tried to split the file into lines and then the lines into words without punctuation.

I am not sure where to go after this. I would like ultimately for the output to be something like this:

```
"your file has x words that are in the list".
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read file content by `with` statement and `open()` method.
2. Remove punctuation from the file content by `string` module.
3. Split file content by `split()` method and iterate every word by `for` loop.
4. Check if word is present in the input list or not and increment `count` value according yo that.

input file: hi.txt

```
hi, how are you?
hi, how are you?
```

code:

```
import string

input_list = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']
filename="hi.txt"
count = 0
with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    data = data.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)  
    for word in data.split():
        if word in input_list:
            count += 1

print "Total number of word present in file from the list are %d"%(count)
```

Output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 18.py 
Total number of word present in file from the list are 8
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$
```

---

1. Do not use variable names which already define by python interpreter

e.g. `list` in your code.

```
>>> list
<type 'list'>
>>> a = list([1,2,3])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list = ["hi", "how"]
>>> b = list([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: a set would be better, for larger input_list.

Comment: set is better but data may contains same world again and again, so by using set operation these duplicate values will not consider. e.g. `>>> set([1,2,3,1])
set([1, 2, 3])` Correct?

Comment: You're right, but I was referring to changing `input_list`. The line `if word in input_list:` will be slow if `input_list` is large, making `input_list` a set doesn't change the result of that line.

Comment: yes, `input_list` is user define list, no item will duplicate in the list. I will check time performance

Answer (score 1):

You can split your file to words using the following command :

```
words=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[line.split() for line in f])
```

Then count the number of words in your word list with loop over it and using `count` function :

```
w_list = ['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you']
with open("hi.txt", "r") as f :
    words=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[line.split() for line in f])
    for w in w_list:
         print "your file has {} {}".format(words.count(w),w)
```

Comment: yep `split` is a better way

Answer (score 1):

```
# words to search for;
# (stored as a set so `word in search_for` is O(1))
search_for = set(["hi", "how", "are", "you"])

# get search text
# (no need to split into lines)
with open("hi.txt") as inf:
    text = inf.read().lower()

# create translation table
# - converts non-word chars to spaces (this maintains appropriate word-breaks)
# - keeps apostrophe (for words like "don't" or "couldn't")
trans = str.maketrans(
    "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'!#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\"\\",
    "          abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'                                 "
)

# apply translation table and split into words
words = text.translate(trans).split()
# count desired words
word_count = sum(word in search_for for word in words)
# show result
print("your file has {} words that are in the list".format(word_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

use the len()
for example for a list; 
`enter code here`
myList = ["c","b","a"]
len(myList)
it will return 3 meaning there are three items on your list.

Comment: That will give you the total number of words, assuming they're split correctly by punctuation, but does not tell the count of words which were contained in the list.